# Can't add modifier to a Text composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I can't add a modifier to a Text in my android app in Jetpack Compose.

I want something like this:

```
Text(
   text = AnnotatedString(resultString),
   Modifer = Modifier.horizontalScroll(scroll),
)
```

But it gives me an error: `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.`

I tried it without the modifier and then it worked.

(I'm using material3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute is `modifier`.

Use

```
Text(
   text = AnnotatedString(resultString),
   modifer = Modifier.horizontalScroll(scroll),
)
```